# "The Print Processor Does Not Exist" when Windows PC tries to connect to shared printer on Ubuntu 16.04.3

Tags: ubuntu, samba, printer

I have a file and print server using Samba version 4.3.11, running Ubuntu 16.04.3 (yes I know this version has reached EOL, I plan to update it after I get this working, I'm trying to not change too many variables at once.) It used to only be a file server but now I'm trying to add printer shares to it. I used [this](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Setting_up_Samba_as_a_Print_Server) tutorial to share the printer, and it seems to have worked. Then, I used [this](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Setting_up_Automatic_Printer_Driver_Downloads_for_Windows_Clients) tutorial to set up automatic driver downloads. This where (I think) I'm having the problem.

When I manually install the printer drivers, the computer connects fine and can see the printer queue (tested on a Windows 10 Pro VM.) However, when I don't have the drivers installed, it finds them on the print$ share and seems to install them, however it can't connect to the printer and shows the "Windows cannot connect to the printer. The print processor does not exist."

I also have CUPS installed on the server and am using that as the backend. Not sure if that's relevant. TIA.